# How to make a range's max value change according to another range's value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two range sliders that I want to be connected somehow. The first one has a minimum of 100 and a maximum of 500. The other one has a minimum of 10 and I want the maximum to be 30% of the other range's value but up to 60. So, for example, if the value of the first range is 300, then the second range's max value has to be 60 even though 30% of 300 is 90. But if the first range's value is 100, then the second range's max value has to be 30, which is 30% of 100.

Here is what I tried to do (but failed):

HTML

```
<form action="#">
                <div class="range-container">
                    <p>Escolha o valor da cobertura de incendio:</p>
                    <div class="value-holder">
                        <label for="range-basica">R$<span id="range-basica-value"></span>k</label>
                    </div>
                    <span>min: R$100k</span>
                    <input id="range-basica" type="range" min="100" max="500" step="50">
                    <span>max: R$500k</span>
                </div>
                <div class="range-container">
                    <div class="value-holder">
                        <label for="range-eletrico">R$<span id="range-eletrico-value"></span>k</label>
                    </div>
                    <p>Escolha o valor da cobertura de danos eletricos:</p>
                    <span>min: R$10k</span>
                    <input id="range-eletrico" type="range" min="10" step="10">
                    <span>max: R$<span id="eletrico-max"></span>k</span>
                </div>

            </form>
```

JS

```
//Basica (Incendio)
let sliderBasica = document.getElementById("range-basica");
let outputBasica = document.getElementById("range-basica-value");
outputBasica.innerHTML = sliderBasica.value;

sliderBasica.oninput = function () {
    outputBasica.innerHTML = this.value;

};

//Danos Eletricos
let sliderEletrico = document.getElementById("range-eletrico");
let outputEletrico = document.getElementById("range-eletrico-value");
let eletricoMaxSpan = document.getElementById("eletrico-max");
let eletricoMax = (sliderBasica.value * 0.3);

outputEletrico.innerHTML = sliderEletrico.value;

sliderEletrico.oninput = function () {
    outputEletrico.innerHTML = this.value;
    if (eletricoMax > 60) {
        eletricoMaxSpan.innerHTML = "60";
        sliderEletrico.setAttribute("max", 60);
    } else if (eletricoMax < 60) {
        eletricoMaxSpan.innerHTML = eletricoMax.toString;
        sliderEletrico.setAttribute("max", eletricoMax);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sliderBasica = document.getElementById("range-basica");
let outputBasica = document.getElementById("range-basica-value");

let sliderEletrico = document.getElementById("range-eletrico");
let outputEletrico = document.getElementById("range-eletrico-value");

sliderBasica.addEventListener("input",(e) => {
  let val = 0.3 * e.target.value
  let setVal = 0
  if (val >= 60) {
    setVal = 60
  } else if (val < 60) {
    setVal = val
  }
  sliderEletrico.max = setVal
  sliderEletrico.value = 0
})
```

Marcelo try this javascript code and ask me if you have any problems understanding it.
I have tried to make it as simple as it can be, the code can be further reduced for better efficiency, but for learning, I think this is enough. Feel free to ask any doubts

Comment: I would go with `sliderElectrico.max = Math.min(val, 60)` instead of that whole `setval` declaration and if statement.

Comment: [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers). What did you change, and why do you think it will help?  What was the problem with OP's code?  Edit your question, add explanations.

Comment: @RickardElimää Thank you for saying that, but as I stated already, the above code can be rewritten for better efficiency, but for understanding of the concept, this was the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked for what I needed it to do. Just had to make a few adjustments to get the numbers to show up  on the page, but other than that, it worked fine. Thanks again...